# comparing efficieny of sql query - using windows function and a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

**I want to understand if my query is correct and if it's efficient than 1st query**

Write a query to display the employee id, first name and last name, SalaryDrawn, AvgCompare (salary - the average salary of all employees) and the SalaryStatus column with a title HIGH and LOW respectively for those employees whose salary is more than and less than the average salary of all employees.

**SAMPLE employee table:**

EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME  | LAST_NAME | SALARY  | MANAGER_ID | DEPARTMENT_ID|

1st Query

```
SELECT  employee_id,  first_name, last_name,  salary AS SalaryDrawn,  
ROUND((salary -(SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employees)),2) AS AvgCompare,  
CASE  WHEN salary >= 
(SELECT AVG(salary) 
FROM employees) THEN 'HIGH'  
ELSE 'LOW'  
END AS SalaryStatus 
FROM employees;
```

My Answer using a CTE and windows function:

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT  employee_id,  first_name, last_name,  salary,
ROUND(AVG(Salary) OVER (),2) AS avgSal 
FROM employees)

Select employee_id, first_name, last_name, salary, ROUND((e.salary - avgSal ,2) AS AvgCompare,  
CASE  WHEN salary >= avgSal THEN 'HIGH'  
ELSE 'LOW'  
END AS SalaryStatus 
FROM cte
```

Comment: Looks correct. Yes, more efficient

Comment: @Charlieface: Do you mind explaining why? Is it because subquery would be calculated for every row in case of first query and that's why the second is more efficient?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say it will be calculated per row, it often is though. But often the compiler will arrange it as a spool, and save that precalculated value. But you would still be scanning the table 3 times instead of once.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to understand if my query is correct

Create some sample data, and the expected results.  Run the query and compare.

> and if it's efficient than 1st query

Look at the [query plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=To%20include%20an%20execution%20plan%20for%20a%20query,the%20Execute%20toolbar%20button.%20...%20More%20items...%20) and the resource utilization.

[SET STATISTICS TIME ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=SET%20STATISTICS%20TIME%20%28Transact-SQL%29%201%20Syntax%202%20Remarks.,parse%2C%20and%20compile%20times.%20...%205%20See%20Also)

[SET STATISTICS IO ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-io-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=SET%20STATISTICS%20IO%20%28Transact-SQL%29%201%20Syntax%202%20Remarks.,Transact-SQL%20statement.%204%20Examples.%20...%205%20See%20Also)

Are an easy ways to see the query resource utilization.